# Союз "как то" без перечисления

Tags: союзы

1. А не бывает у тебя подспудной тревоги, когда чем-то занимаешься, как то общение с друзьями?
2. Как то общением с друзьями
3. Как то: общение с друзьями

Может ли за союзом "как то" последовать не перечисление, а пример, частный случай? Сохраняется ли в этом случае управление?

Answer (score 1):

Союз *как то* используется [только перед перечислением](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_354&layout=item).

Comment: Согласен, если ‟как-то” и может использоваться не перед перечислением, то только в какой-то сумбурно-разговорной речи.